# Solving an overdetermined system of non-linear equations while maximizing a different function

Tags: r, minimization

I'm having trouble trying to implement this in R. I have a user-defined, non-linear function that takes a vector `x` and gives another vector `F` as output. In addition, I have a second function `L` that takes the vector and gives a number as output (which is, in fact, related to the likelihood of `x`, but this is not relevant for the question). Here is how these functions could look like (I just made these up as an example):

```
F <- function(x) {
  c(
    exp(x[1]*(1-x[2])) / (exp(x[1]*(1-x[2])) + exp(x[3]*(1-x[4]))) - 0.2,
    exp(x[3]*(1-x[4])) / (exp(x[1]*(1-x[2])) + exp(x[3]*(1-x[4]))) - 0.8
    )
}

L <- function(x) {
  0.5^exp(x[1]*abs(x[4]-x[2]))
}
```

On one hand, I want to find the values of `x` that minimize `F` (i.e. I want to solve `F(x)=0`), but that's not all. First, the system `F(x)=0` is always overdetermined. What I want to do is to find the solution with the maximum `L(x)` out of all the possible ones. I thought I could try to just minimize something like `sum(F(x)) + 1/L(x)`, but I see a few problems with this (for instance, the scales of `F` and `L` can be very different and I don't know them beforehand).

If anyone knew a way to approach this it would be awesome. Thanks in advance!

J

Comment: Damn! I made a mistake when "translating" my code into a minimal example. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: The maximum value of L is infinite since x[1] and x[3] may have any value and it is still possible to guarantee that F = 0 by setting x[2] and x[4] appropriately.

Comment: Regardless of the particular properties of your example function, this is a _constrained nonlinear optimization_ problem.  You should read up on that area.  It looks like potential packages to check out are `nloptr`, `NlcOptim`, and `constrOptim.nl`.

Comment: I haven't mentioned but the values of the x[i] are constrained (e.g. they must lie within the interval [0,1]). I thought that this could be easily taken into account by forcing L(x)=0 for values that don't satisfy the constraints, so I have a more clear idea of how to impose that conditions. I have, however, modified the function in the example to make it better resemble the actual form it has in my case. Thanks for the assist! I will look into the packages Curt has mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the following approach :

```
library(DEoptim)

fn_Opt <- function(x, bool_Print = FALSE)
{
  term1 <- (exp(x[1] * (1 - x[2])) / (exp(x[1] * (1 - x[2])) + exp(x[3] * (1 - x[4]))) - 0.2) 
  term2 <- (exp(x[3] * (1 - x[4])) / (exp(x[1] * (1 - x[2])) + exp(x[3] * (1 - x[4]))) - 0.8) 
  term3 <- (0.5 ^ exp(x[1] * abs(x[4] - x[2])))
  val_Ret <- term1 + term2 - term3
  
  if(bool_Print == TRUE)
  {
    print("term1")
    print(term1)
    print("term2")
    print(term2)
    print("term3")
    print(term3)
  }
  
  if(is.nan(val_Ret))
  {
    return(10 ^ 30)
    
  }else
  {
    return(val_Ret)
  }
}

obj_DEoptim <- DEoptim(fn = fn_Opt, lower = rep(0, 4), upper = rep(1, 4), control = list(itermax = 1000))
fn_Opt(x = obj_DEoptim$optim$bestmem, bool_Print = TRUE)
```

It seems that there is more than one solution to this problem.